# google maps in my android application

Tags: android, google-maps

I have application which uses Google Maps. Also I created "custom My Map" on Google account in Google maps. So the question is next -  can I use MapView control to show this specific "custom My Map" on device?

Comment: By "my map", are you referring to [Google My Maps](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=21670&topic=21676&from=21676&rd=2) or something else?

Comment: Exactly, I need to show my map on my android component. Do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there isn't any API to access your stored "My Maps" data.

The only way I can think of doing it is to export your My Maps as a KML file, as described [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapstips/export-my-map-as-kml). From that you can retrieve the file via a server or locally onto your Android app and parse it manually to find the location.

Another option is to use the link in the KML file and view it on the app via a WebView or something in the essence.

These are just speculations of course, but it is how I would approach it.